# Find the value of $(\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{y})^{-2024}$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{y}}+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{y}}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{11}\right)$$
> $$\sqrt{y+\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{y-\sqrt{x}}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{11}\right)$$ Then find the value of
> $$(\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{y})^{-2024}$$

I applied $$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$ and got
$$2\left(x+y+\sqrt{x^2-y}-\sqrt{y^2-x}\right)=1$$
I'm stuck here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are $x,$ and $y$ real numbers?

Comment: @ajotatxe apparently not, because both $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt{-x}$ seem to be defined. Also, I’d even go as far to conjecture that $x\pm\sqrt y$ and $y\pm\sqrt x$ are also real, otherwise their square roots are not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the initial equations there is unfortunately a typo. In my opinion it should be:

$$S = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{y}} \space + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{y}} $$
$$C = \sqrt{y + \sqrt{x}} \space + \sqrt{y - \sqrt{x}} $$

Where for convenience we have introduced $S = \sin(\pi/11)$ and $C = \cos(\pi/11)$. To get rid of some of the square roots, square both formulas.

$$S^2 = 2x + 2\sqrt{x^2-y}$$
$$C^2 = 2y + 2\sqrt{y^2-x}$$

Bring the terms $2x$ and $2y$ to the left, square both sides and simplify.

$$S^4 -4S^2x+4y = 0$$
$$C^4 -4C^2y+4x = 0$$

These are two linear equations that are easily solved. The result is $x = -C^2/4$ and $y=-S^2/4$.

We substitute these expressions into the target function $(\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{y})^{-2024}$ , which becomes $(\frac {1}{2}(\cos(\pi/11)+i \sin(\pi/11))^{-2024}$. This is equal to $(\frac {1}{2}\exp(i\pi/11)/2)^{-2024}$.
Since $2024$ is equal to $92 * 22$, i.e. a multiple of $22$, the phase factor is equal to unity. The result is $2^{2024}$.

Comment: (+1) I think you're right...even wolframalpha shows that there exists no solution for the original system of equations...in either case you're a maven but can you pls use the frac command for I am not able to get the place of 1/2